# cocoa: NSView touch event

Tags: cocoa, touch, nsview

I created a simple cocoa project, and added an `NSButton` in the window.
Then I added an `NSScrollView` to the window and hided the `NSButton`. 
However, when I click the scroll view , it is strange that the `NSButton` action responds!

I guess there is something with the touch event chains, but I failed to find it.
For example, I try to use:

```
- [NSView becomeFirstResponder];
- [NSView setAcceptsTouchEvents:];
```

SO what I want is the only the front-most view to become the first responder, and the touch event will not be sent to its superview or so.

Thanks.
This is the view hierarchy:

[image]

the scroll view and button are both added to the window view, and the scrollview's frame includes the button's frame. In other words, the button is hidden by the scroll view but still receives click events.

Comment: Wait, the NSScrollView is a child view of the NSButton?

Comment: @rein, no. I edited, and Pls refer to the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `mouseDown:` event in `NSScrollView` or `NSCrollView`'s View. like this:

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"MouseDown in NSView");
}
```

Comment: the point doesn't matter with the button. I don't want the touch event in the scroll view to be sent to the sibling view (in this situation it is the button).